# Easter Egg - letter spacing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I created a little easter egg. When you hover over the `h1` title, letters are created, and animated letters fall to the bottom of the page. I wanted to create more spacing between the letters as the fall so they aren't all mushed together.

To do that, I did:

```
                myspan.css({
                    "color" : "Navy",
                    "position": "absolute",
                    "margin" : "20px",
                    "padding" : "20px",
                    "left": $(this).position().left,
                    "top": parent.height()
                });
```

[image]

**But it didn't work. Any thoughts? Here's the code:**

```
            $(".title").lettering(); //splits H1 letters into individual spans
            $("h1 span").mouseenter(function () {   

                var colors = ["White"],
                    rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*colors.length-1)+1),
                    string = "National Champs!",
                    letter = string.charAt(index),
                    myspan = $(document.createElement('span')),

                    parent = $(this).parent(),
                    val = $(this);

                if (index >= string.length) {
                    index = 0;
                }
                else {
                    index++;
                }

                myspan.append(letter);
                parent.append(myspan);
                myspan.css({
                    "color" : "Navy",
                    "position": "absolute",
                    "margin" : "20px",
                    "padding" : "20px",
                    "left": $(this).position().left,
                    "top": parent.height()
                });
                myspan.animate({"top": $(window).outerHeight()}, 9000, "linear", function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                });

                val.css({"color" : colors[rand]});

                setTimeout(function() { 
                    val.css({"color" : "black"});
                    val.css({"font-size" : 35}); 
                    //index =0;
                },2000);            
            });
```

---

EDIT:

I did

```
myspan.css({
                    "color" : "Navy",
                    "position": "absolute",
                    "letter-spacing" : "2px",
                    "left": $(this).position().left,
                    "top": parent.height()
                });
```

This didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the css atrribute `letter-spacing` may help

```
 letter-spacing:2px
```

Comment: Am I doing it incorrectly? Please see above

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide units for `letter-spacing`, value `2` alone doesn't mean anything. I assume you are thinking about pixels, so in this case that would be:

```
myspan.css({
    "color" : "Navy",
    "position": "absolute",
    "letter-spacing" : "2px",
    "left": $(this).position().left,
    "top": parent.height()
});
```

Please check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing

Comment: Yes I have the `px` in my code... forgot to post it here for some reason. It still doesn't work with that.